# Mathematical symbol describing variables that increase together

Tags: notation, approximation, approximation-theory

If I have a pair of functions increasing together or decreasing together, I certainly have:

\begin{equation}
min(|\Delta F|,|\Delta G|) > 0 \iff \frac{\Delta F}{\Delta G} > 0
\end{equation}

I am tempted to express this relationship as follows:

\begin{equation}
\forall x \in \mathbb{R},F(x) \propto G(x)
\end{equation}

However, $\propto$ is not quite the appropriate symbol as I'm trying to describe variables which aren't necessarily proportional to each other. This problem, which might seem contrived, actually occurred in the context where I'm trying to calculate:

\begin{equation}
\max_{x} F(x)  =\int_{t=0}^x f(t) dt 
\end{equation}

However, $F(x)$ is an intractable expression whereas I found a different function $G$ such that $G(x)$ is tractable so instead I calculate:

\begin{equation}
\max_{x} G(x)
\end{equation}

I noticed that this kind of trick regularly appears for the types of problems I'm trying to solve, so I think such a symbol must already exist.

**Note:** I am still wondering whether $\propto$ might be sufficient. I might be overcomplicating this.

Comment: Are $F$ and $G$ differentiable? If so, maybe $F'(x)G'(x)\ge0$? (not sure if there is a symbol though)

Comment: @Shuri2060 In general, I can't assume differentiability of both $F$ and $G$.

Comment: is one always higher than the other if so you might use some type of asymptotic notation.

Comment: or you might just try $\approx$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee All I can guarantee is that when $F$ increases so does $G$.

Comment: I actually just prefer the first thing you wrote.

Comment: Really, the thing I prefer most is just using words.  Oftentimes this is the most clearest thing for the reader, which is the point of writing, isn't it?

Comment: @Randall while I agree to some extent , I also think it depends on audience. writing in notation avoids the language barrier if the notation is consistent between sets of people., it becomes a language in itself. of course if the notation is not well known/ used, it may still have to be described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that there is any special symbol for this relationship between two functions of real numbers, so perhaps it is best to pick some little-used symbol and define it to mean that in your context.

For example:

If $F,G: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ then $F\bowtie G$ means that if $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a\le b$ then $F(a)\le F(b)\iff G(a)\le G(b)$ and $F(a)\ge F(b)\iff G(a)\ge G(b)$.

Comment: I think it would be context dependent,  $f(x)=\mathcal{O}(g(x))$ or other notations would be used in asymptotics. numerical approximations use $\approx$. etc.